# JUJU-MAAS controller problem

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, conjure-up

Greeting
Im trying to run OpenStack on couple of bare metal server's
MAAS is installed, vlan's were ok and for now im truing to run OpenStack  default configuration.
However, after 1000 faulty attempt's  to install if with conjure, i decide to run configure manually.
I remove all previously defined controller's, logins, e.t.c and as far as im typing

```
juju deploy --constraints tags=juju cloudName controllerName
```

Instantly getting error

```
ERROR failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance in availability zone "default": failed to acquire node: No available machine matches constraints: [('mem', ['3584']), ('zone', ['default']), ('agent_name', ['9d3f016e-b330-4713-8400-5b6ef43c01e1'])] (resolved to "mem=3584.0 zone=default")
```

So, i can't add model, machines or even run something. How i can remove this pre-defined config, or, were is need to take a look?
Thank for reading this, and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing the original juju folder name that was installed

If installed by conjure-up:

Change directories

```
cd ~/.local/share
```

View contents of directory

```
ls
```

Change (move) folder name (juju) to different folder name (old).  This will keep it from being read and allow you to change (move) it back if needed.

```
mv juju old
```